# Question on the definition of a unique linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling with the precise consequences of a linear map (between two vector spaces) being unique. I understand what a linear map between two vector spaces is, but I don't understand really what it means for one to be unique.

What are the requirements for a linear map to be unique? Are there any obvious consequences?

Any examples (inside or outside the context of vector spaces) would be useful.

I've had a look at this question [How to show a linear map is unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251454/how-to-show-a-linear-map-is-unique) which is quite helpful, but I don't completely yet understand.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

"Unique" in math means that there is one and only one.  For example, there is a unique solution to $x+1=5$, namely $x=4$.  But, there is not a unique solution to $x^2=4$, because $x=2$ and $x=-2$ both solve it.

Since I am uncertain of the context of your problem, here is an example from linear algebra.  Suppose we want a linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $L(1,0)=(1,1,1)$ and $L(0,1)=(0,0,1)$.  Then the solution to this problem is unique.  There is only one linear transformation that satisfies those two equations.  That's because we can define a linear transformation by specifying values for any basis.

In contrast, there are many linear transformations that satisfy just the first equation $L(1,0)=(1,1,1)$.  Let 
$$
L_1(x,y)=(x,x,x).
$$
Then $L_1(1,0)=(1,1,1)$ as requested.  But, we could also define
$$
L_2(x,y)=(x-y,x-y,x-y).
$$
This also has the property that $L_2(1,0)=(1,1,1)$.  But, the two transformations are not the same.  For instance $L_1(0,1)=(0,0,0)$, whereas $L_2(0,1)=(-1,-1,-1)$.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. The part which I don't understand is how there are many linear transformations that satisfy just the first equation. Why is that the case? Is there any chance you could give examples of some?

Comment: You could let $L(0,1)=(0,0,0)$ instead, or $L(0,1)=(1,\pi,\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: And in those two cases the linear map is not the same. I think I understand! Thanks again.

Comment: @Matt I added an example.